# calculate the time passed after an entry of date with the current time of the day

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
     PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into mydate values(?,?)");

         java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();

         pStmt.setDate( 1, new java.sql.Date( now.getTime()) );


         pStmt.setTimestamp( 2, new java.sql.Timestamp( now.getTime() ) );
          pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

QUERY1:
I am creating post a  comment module .I want to display the time when user posted their comments.also i want to show the time passed after they have posted a comment.
 like 2 days ago ,5 min before etc.

QUERY2:
i also want to change the format of the date to dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the date formatted you can use java.text.SimpleDateFormat or 
org.apache.commons.lang.time.FastDateFormat

For the time intervals you can use org.apache.commons.lang.time.DurationFormatUtils

Here is a sample:

```
//this will get the date in format dd/mm/yyyy
FastDateFormat fmt = FastDateFormat.getInstance("dd/MM/yyyy");
String txt = fmt.format(date);

//this will get the interval
long ival = System.currentTimeMilis()-date.getTime();
String interval = DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationWords(ival, true, true);
```

Comment: can you explain it with the help of example

Comment: String interval = DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationWords(ival, true, true); line is showing error in netbeans

Comment: String interval = DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationWords(ival, true, true);
is giving error in netbeans

Comment: I don't get error. It will help if you tell me what error do you get.

Comment: DurationFormatUtils it is getting underlined .ERROE IS:CREATE class DurationFormatUtils in package.I am using netbeans ide 6.8 and glassfish server

Comment: netbeans can't find the class. Check that you have the jar in the classpath and that you are correctly importing the package